# I was a Green Card holder and I have NEXUS. I became a US citizen, do I need to update NEXUS?

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, nexus

I have NEXUS and I had a GC at the time of application. I now am a US citizen and I maintained my other nationality (dual citizen). Does my NEXUS still work and do I need to update NEXUS?

Comment: You surely need to update it, but I can't find an official US government source saying so, so I will refrain from posting an answer.  I did find a Canadian government source, but I don't know whether it is directly applicable to someone who joined the program in the US: https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/prog/nexus/contact-coordonnees-eng.html

Comment: Both U.S. and Canadian rules should apply to NEXUS holders (and both governments can unilaterally revoke membership). Additionally updating your citizenship information would allow you to fully utilize NEXUS benefits without needing your passport.

Comment: @phoog why surely?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt because the legal basis for the person's crossing the border has changed.